# How can I automatically enable notifications in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there anyway to use `selenium` to activate notifications automactically using a selenium webdriver? So far what I've learned doesn't work. Even in other stackoverflow questions.

Here is the code that I've been using

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument('--enable-notifications')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=option)
driver.get("https://example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Allow Notifications**

The default behavior for Chrome Browser is to ask allow or block notifications. And corresponding dialogue popup will be shown.

Notifications will be automatically allowed without showing allow/block message with the next configuration:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 1}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=option)
```

For testing how it works execute the next lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#start the driver
option = Options()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 1}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=option)

#check the behavior on notification demo site
driver.get("https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Example Notification']"))).click()
```

**Dismiss Notifications**

This configuration for dismiss notifications without showing allow/block message.

```
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
```

Comment: What packages do I have to add in python? unfortunately i don't understand the code :c could you give me an example? So a whole code that automatically allows notifications on a website, then it would be more understandable, would be really nice

Kind regards.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed you are using python. I've added java code.. I'll add the same for python.

Comment: @KjellKöcher see my update.

Comment: Oh oh Thank you no problem

Comment: I have a other question, did you know how i can use a proxy LIST in selenium?

Comment: @KjellKöcher feel free to post a new question regarding proxy list. Someone from the community might help. And also, please, concider accepting my answer, if it solved your original issue https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Or provide some feedback if not helped.